# how to use computeArea to calculate the area of a circle?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

google maps geometry library provides a function:

computeArea(loop:Array.|MVCArray., radius?:number)

which seems can calculate the area of a circle by providing the radius, but no matter how I tried, it didn't seem to work. Any help of how I can use the function?

BTW, fowllowing is a sample of calculating the area of a polygon:

```
    var nyc = new google.maps.LatLng(40.715, -74.002);
    var london = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506, -0.119);
    var rio = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.916, -43.251);
    var area = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeArea([nyc, london, rio]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the radius to calculate the area of a circle.  This function only computes the area of a polygon.  The radius parameter is the radius of the earth.  The default value is 6378137 meters.  If you want the area returned in km, ft, miles, etc you provide the earths radius in the desired unit.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for a circle doesn't require the Google Maps API, you can simply calculate it using Math.PI in JavaScript:

```
function area (radius){

return radius*radius*Math.PI
}
```

Math.PI is built into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping computeArea could give a different result from simply doing radius*radius*Math.PI, assuming the function works for circles.

Comment: Why would it give a different result? That is how one calculates the area of a circle, it's well known geometry.

Comment: how can i get the circle radius from the Circle that i draw on the map?

Comment: @xmux assuming your circle object is MyCircle, MyCircle.getRadius() returns it in meters.

Comment: i found it later on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695652/google-maps-get-radius btw:thanks!